# Trouble with local variable not being used

Tags: python

I'm new to python and have had trouble defining variable `d` (which stores input from `difficulty()`) in a memory game program.

Pycharm says that the variable is not being used even though I've tried to put it to use in a separate `elif` statement. Does anyone have any advice?

```
def main_menu():
    user_123 = int((input(" | Enter an option : ")))
    while user_123 > 3 or user_123 < 1:
        user_123 = int(input("Incorrect option, try again:"))
        return user_123

def difficulty():
    d = int(input("Please verify the level of difficulty [1-5]: "))
    while d > 5 or d < 1:
        d = int(input(("Please enter a valid number [1-5]: ")))
        main_menu()
    return d

def main():
    high_score = [0]
    d = 1

print("  ========== MEMO GAME ========== \n |                               | "
      "\n | 1. Choose level of difficulty | \n | 2. Start Game                 |"
      "\n | 3. Exit the Game              | \n |                               "
      "\n | Current Difficulty: ", d, " \n | Highest score reached: ", high_score)
use = str(main_menu())
if use == "1":
    d = (difficulty())
elif use == "2":
    d = str(difficulty())
    if d == "1":
        p1 = level1.first_level()
        high_score.append(p1)
    elif d == "2":
        p2 = level2.second_level()
        high_score.append(p2)
```

Comment: If `use` is equal to `"1"`, then you define `d` but don't use it anywhere. Also, considering the way the code after `d=1` is indented, it's _outside_ the `main` function, so the `d` is a _global_ variable.

Comment: You already convert all your `input()`s to `int`, which is fine, but you then need to compare them to ints. eg: `if use == 1:`. Plus you call `main_menu()` from within `difficulty()`. Don't do that.

Comment: Apart from other comments, your main_menu return should be out of while loop.

Answer (score 1):

There are a bunch of indentation errors in the code, so the variables you're defining aren't necessarily available at the points where you think they are.  Here's a fixed version (I think -- I can't run it because I don't have `level1` and `level2`):

```
def main_menu():
    user_123 = input(" | Enter an option : ")
    while user_123 not in set("123"):
        user_123 = input("Incorrect option, try again:")
    return user_123

def difficulty():
    d = input("Please verify the level of difficulty [1-5]: ")
    while d not in set("12345"):
        d = input("Please enter a valid number [1-5]: ")
    return d

def main():
    high_score = [0]
    d = "1"

    while True:
        print(
            f"  ========== MEMO GAME ========== \n"
            f" |                               |\n"
            f" | 1. Choose level of difficulty |\n"
            f" | 2. Start Game                 |\n"
            f" | 3. Exit the Game              |\n"
            f" |                               |\n"
            f" | Current Difficulty: {d}       |\n"
            f" | Highest score reached: {high_score}"
        )
        use = main_menu()
        if use == "1":
            d = difficulty()
        elif use == "2":
            if d == "1":
                score = level1.first_level()
            elif d == "2":
                score = level2.second_level()
            else:
                score = 0
            high_score.append(score)
        else:
            break

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Note that in `main_menu` and `difficulty`, you need to `return` the answer *after* the loop if you want it to be the "correct" one that broke the loop.  Since you plan to use these values as strings, there's no need to convert them to `int`; all that does is give you an opportunity for a `ValueError` if the user enters something non-numeric.

In `main()` it seems like you want a loop to let the user pick different items from the menu, so I added that loop, and also fixed the indentation so that all the code after `main()` is actually inside that function.  I also made sure that we only call `main_menu()` when it's time to actually pick a menu item (at the start of the loop), and we only call `difficulty()` when it's time to pick a difficulty (when the user picks "1").

A change I might suggest making would be to rename `high_score` to `scores`, and use `max(scores)` when you want to get the high score.

Comment: Why using `f` formatting in all the strings? also, I believe the `\n` can be avoided setting `sep="\n"` and separating the strings with `,` (comma)

Comment: 1) alignment 2) sure (`,` is a comma, though, not a colon)

Comment: Thank you so much! That makes a lot more sense. I appreciate your clarification regarding the placement of difficulty() and main_menu(), as well.